# Deploying a site as a role to Azure - DirectoryNotFoundException - approot / siteroot

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I've been examining the event logs for the WebApp I'm trying to automatically deploy and the only problem I can find is this (Azure event log):

```
An unhandled exception occurred. Type: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException Process ID: 1784
Process Name: WaIISHost
Thread ID: 1
AppDomain Unhandled Exception for role Website_IN_0
Exception: Could not find a part of the path 'E:\approot'.
```

So I have a poke and sure enough, nothing lives there and the directory doesn't even exist. However I then realise the site exists in E:\sitesroot.... so why is it looking in approot?

This is my service definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="WebsiteAzure" xmlns="etc">
  <WebRole name="Website" vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
    </Endpoints>
    <Imports>
      <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
    </Imports>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

Is that right?

For the record the deployment works fine with visual studio but i'm trying to automate with powershell which is where I'm getting the issue. I'm pretty sure it has all the .dlls it requires and the config and definition are correct so why is it choking on this directory?

Comment: Create a new cloud project, add a MVC4 role, deploy with VS. The code VS/Azure SDK 1.8 creates is correct (like the service def above). Use ftp to figure out what's missing.

Comment: How are you packaging the service? Through visual studio? cspack.exe? msbuild publish target?

Comment: msbuild  cspack with a powershell script to publish. New-AzureDeployment.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using New-AzureServiceProject and add-azure*webrole to scaffold the project locally, and using Publish-AzureServiceProject to package and publish to Azure.